# How does register flushing work when synchronized is used?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, cpu-registers, java-memory-model

I read from the book «Java Performance» that the following code is found to be taking a surprising amount of time with running on a machine with many registers:

```
Vector v = initVector();
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        process(v.get(i));
    }
```

Because the get() and size() methods of the Vector class are synchronised, and it turned out that the register flushing (to the main memory) required by all those calls is a huge performance problem.

One way to avoid that is to wrap lots of successive, fine-grained synchronisation calls within a synchronized block, as the following:

```
Vector v = initVector();
    synchronized (v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            process(v.get(i));
        }
    }
```

I do have the following questions:

1. Why the register flushing is expensive even though the size() and get() methods don't change the value of the variable in the register? In my opinion, there is nothing to be flushed back to the main memory. Am I wrong?
2. Does the solution suggested by the author mean that once a few inner successive synchronized methods  are wrapped in a outer synchronized call, inner ones don't do the register flushing anymore, and there will only be one single final register flushing at the outer level?

Thank you!

Comment: That book really only applies to a particular version of the JVM (jdk7u40 and jdk8 first release) so I'd be careful tuning your app too much. In this particular case, the author is quite skimpy on the details - no mention whether this benchmark is about contended or uncontended synchronisation. But the answers should be 1. because the Java Memory Model requires *all* data from one thread to become visible to another thread that synchronises on the same lock, and keeping track would take more time than flushing. and 2. Yes

Comment: I would expect the JIT to do the proposed optimisation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read-only methods still need to acquire the lock, or else another Thread would be able to make changes while you are reading, causing random behavior.
2. The solution suggested by the author acquires the lock only once, before the loop begins, and releases it at the end. This way, you skip the many lock/release cycles that would occur if you have to acquire the lock every step of the loop.